# Tracking the Sun from Sunrise in the East to Sunset in the West

Tags: azimuth, sunrise, sunset, tracker

Is there a Correct way to mathematically allocate GPS/location of Azimuth Degrees ?

EG:
In the Southern Hemisphere, if North is 0 degrees, for say Sydney **is direct East 90 or -90 degrees ?**
Then what **is direct West -90 degrees or 270 degrees for southern hemisphere ?**

Assuming the degrees go from North=0, and goes Clockwise to 360 degrees?

And **is Northern Hemisphere the opposite ?**

As I am unsure how these are correctly used for following the Sun position through the sky, in mathematical terms!

Comment: Yes, it always goes clockwise. It's *usually* measured from the north, but not always. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azimuth

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematically allocate GPS/location of Azimuth Degrees"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventionally, 0 is North, 90 is East, 180 is South and 270 is West;  in both the Northern and Southern Hemisphere. These are directions.

This is nothing to do with GPS, which is about location, not direction.

Comment: Thanks, that is the type of information I am looking for.
As I am trying to Track the Sun from Sunrise to Sunset, and the de-bug Manual for dual axis tracking is very confusing as it a Chinese version of how to do this.
However the Manual uses  statements like -90 degrees.

Comment: -90 = 270  degrees

Comment: So, that must indicate the Software Only relates to working Backwards & Forwards from North position, where obviously North is 0 degrees !